# How to upload image with FILE_URI distination to firebase storage in Ionic 2

Tags: image, firebase, upload, ionic2, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload captured image to firebase storage after edit it by some custom editor.

My problem under two cases:

- Case1 : If I used this code, then I can upload the image **but I can't use my custom editor**

  ```
  takePicture(){
    let options: CameraOptions;
    options = {
      quality : 85,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : false,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.currentOriginalImageUri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.currentDocumentImageUri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    });
  }
  ```
- Case2 : If I used this code, then I can use the function of custom editor **but I can't upload my image**

  ```
  takePicture(){
    let options: CameraOptions;
    options = {
      quality : 85,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : false,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.currentOriginalImageUri = imageData;
      this.currentDocumentImageUri = imageData;
    });
  }
  ```

Note: This is my uploading function

```
   private uploadPhoto(): void {
      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
         content: ""
      })
    loader.present().then(_=>{
       return this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.JPEG').putString(this.currentDocumentImageUri,firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then((savedPicture) => {
            this.currentDocumentImageUri = savedPicture.downloadURL;
            this.afd.list('/notesImages/').push({
                note_id: this.appService.id,
                url: this.currentDocumentImageUri,
                date: new Date().toISOString()
            });
        });
    }).then(_=>{
        loader.dismiss();
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    })
}
```

So is there any way to use the both cases?

Comment: you are using file_url in one and data_url in the other. Did you change `firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL` while testing with file url?

Comment: @SurajRao change it to the what ?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving image as a string in the database. If you want to *upload a file* using file path using the [linked api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) (assuming data_url is not working for your custom editor)

Try `put()` instead of `putString()`.

```
return this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.JPEG').put(this.currentDocumentImageUri).then((savedPicture) => {
 // rest of code
});
```

Comment: Thank, I Checked this but still image cant be uploaded in storage firebase

Comment: did you try adding catch to the promise and logging error?

Comment: I checked there is no errors .. I think the problem in local path .. I think I should convert it for something to can upload the image on firebase .. because the path such as " file:///storage/emulated....jpg"